# Postgres efficiently check JSONB contains while skipping missing values

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table with a JSONB `sub` column that holds an array of json objects as follows.

```
[{
    "a": "alpha",
    "b": "bravo",
    "country": "usa"
},
{
    "a": "alpha",
    "b": "bravo",
    "country": "canada"
}]
```

Now my web service needs to find if a row in the table has at least one object that matches the request json object. But only for the properties that it actually has in the array objects, any unknown properties should be ignored.

In other words, the following request would match because the row has an object with properties a, and b, and country that match an object in the array.

```
{
  "a": "alpha",
  "b": "bravo",
  "country": "usa",
  "x": "XRAY",
  "z": "ZULU",
}
```

I tried using the jsonb `@>` operator which can look for matches inside the array, but it expects all of the properties to be there. So the following query does not work because of the unknown x and z properties.

```
select *
from table t
where sub @> '[{"a": "alpha","b": "bravo","country": "usa","x": "XRAY","z": "ZULU"}]'::jsonb
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `@>` against each *item* in the array - not on the array itself. [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) comes in handy here.

```
testdb=# with fake_input_data as (
select ARRAY['{"a": "alpha", "b": "bravo", "country": "usa"}',
        '{"a": "alpha", "b": "bravo", "country": "canada"}']::jsonb[] sub
)

SELECT sub from fake_input_data
WHERE '{"a": "alpha", "b": "bravo", "country": "usa", "x": "xray"}'::jsonb @> ANY(sub);
                                                              sub                                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"{\"a\": \"alpha\", \"b\": \"bravo\", \"country\": \"usa\"}","{\"a\": \"alpha\", \"b\": \"bravo\", \"country\": \"canada\"}"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Does `jsonb_array_elements_text` have to be used in your answer somehow? I am seeing `[42809] ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side`.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be required. Do you have ANY(sub) on the right side of the `@>`? The error message implies you don't. Unfortunately, you can't just use `ANY(x) <@ y` or `y @> ANY(x)` interchangably - ANY has to be on the right-hand-side for reasons I think I used to know but can no longer remember :)